# Nested Eloquent model events not firing in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a medical web app built with Laravel 5.2 where I need to delete records related with a patient when they are deleted. I am unable to delete them with Eloquent events.

A patient has many encounters which belong to that patient, and that encounter has many EncounterSymptoms that belong to that encounter.
Here is my database schema:
[image: EncounterSymptom should be deleted when an Encounter is deleted.]

Currently, my method to delete all of the patient's 'encounters' is deleting them when the patient is deleted is deleting the associated encounters by listening when eloquent models fire:

```
//In App\Models\Patient\Patient.php
public function Encounters(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Patient\Encounter');
}

protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($Patient) { 
         $Patient->Encounters()->delete();
    });
}
```

In my Encounter model, I have this:

```
    //In App\Models\Patient\Encounter.php
    public function EncounterSymptoms(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Encounter\EncounterSymptom');
    }
    protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::deleting(function($Encounter) {
         $Encounter->EncounterSymptoms()->delete();
    });
    }
```

Using tinker, I selected an instance of Encounter, then deleted it, which did delete related EncounterSymptom records, but When I call a delete on a patient, all associated Encounters are successfully deleted, but EncounterSymptoms are not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's a soft deleting issue with EncounterSymptoms table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using migrations, you need to set the `onDelete` cascade.

For example, when creating the Encounters table:

```
$table->foreign('patient_id')
      ->references('id')->on('Patients')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Similarly, on the EncounterSymptom table:

```
$table->foreign('encounter_id')
      ->references('id')->on('Encounters')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

See Migrations -> [Foreign Key Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) section in the docs.